# Java Arraylist gets filled but doesn't update?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to make an app that gets live game scores, but am having trouble with the recycleviewer and arraylist.

The RecycleView works fine but my trouble occurs when I am making the arraylist to fill the RecycleView with. Here I just fill the array with 100 games objects, and this works. I get the screen to fill with 100 random games.

```
private void updateUI() {

    ArrayList<Games> games = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Games g = new Games("t1",110);
        g.setTeam2("T2");
        g.setTeam2_score(120);
        games.add(g);
    }
    mAdapter = new GameAdapter(games);
    mGameRecycleViewer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I don't want just any random 100 objects, I want to get the games that happened on a day and fill the array with them. So I use JSON to get the games, and I know the array gets filled with the games because of this log message I put:
Log.d("AAAAAHHHHHHH",Integer.toString(games.size())); that tells me the size of the array I get this output:

```
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 1
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 2
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 2
 D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 3
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 3
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 4
 D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 4
 D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 5
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 5
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 6
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 6
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 7
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 7
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 8
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 8
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 9
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 9
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 10
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 10
D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 11
 D/AAAAAHHHHHHH: 11
```

Also, I tried the JSON without using the recycle viewer and outputting everything on screen so that works too. The issue is that nothing stays in the games array for some reason, even though the above shows its there. It doesn't show up on screen.

I also added another logd right after execute and it says the size is 0:         Log.d("OOOHHHHHHH",Integer.toString(games.size()));

So for some reason the array doesn't get filled outside run class.
Anyone have any advice, or know how to fixit?

Here is the updateUI Using JSON:

```
ArrayList<Games> games = new ArrayList<>();

private void updateUI() {
    class run extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String line = "";
        String data = "";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=02/13/2019&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                while(line!=null){
                    line = bf.readLine();
                    data += line;
                }
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("resultSets");
                JSONObject jo2 = (JSONObject) ja.get(1);//Linescores
                JSONArray ja3 = (JSONArray) jo2.get("rowSet");
                JSONArray ja4;

                int count = 0;
                for(int i = 0;i<ja3.length();i++){
                    ja4 = new JSONArray(ja3.get(i).toString());
                    //teams+=ja4.get(4)+": score =  "+ja4.get(21).toString()+"\n";
                    if(count == 1) {
                        games.get(games.size() - 1).setTeam2(ja4.get(4).toString());
                        games.get(games.size() - 1).setTeam2_score(Integer.parseInt(ja4.get(21).toString()));
                        count = 0;
                    }else{
                        games.add(new Games(ja4.get(4).toString(), Integer.parseInt(ja4.get(21).toString())));
                        count = 1;
                    }
                    Log.d("AAAAAHHHHHHH",Integer.toString(games.size()));
                }




            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //main.setText(teams);

        }
    }
    run r = new run();

    r.execute();
    mAdapter = new GameAdapter(games);
    mGameRecycleViewer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Here is the full RecycleViewer:

```
public class GameListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mGameRecycleViewer;
private GameAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_list, container, false);
    mGameRecycleViewer = (RecyclerView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.game_recycler_view);
    mGameRecycleViewer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

private class GameHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public GameHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_game_item, parent, false));
    }

}
private class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameHolder> {
    private List<Games> mGames;
    public GameAdapter(List<Games> crimes) {
        mGames = crimes;
    }
    @Override
    public GameHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new GameHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GameHolder holder, int position) {
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGames.size();
    }

}
ArrayList<Games> games = new ArrayList<>();

private void updateUI() {
    //GameLab gamelab = GameLab.get(getActivity());
    //ArrayList<Games> crimes = gamelab.getGames();
    //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //Games g = new Games("t1",110);
        //g.setTeam2("T2");
        //g.setTeam2_score(120);
        //games.add(g);
    //}
    class run extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String line = "";
        String data = "";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=02/13/2019&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                while(line!=null){
                    line = bf.readLine();
                    data += line;
                }
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);

                JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("resultSets");
                JSONObject jo2 = (JSONObject) ja.get(1);//Linescores
                JSONArray ja3 = (JSONArray) jo2.get("rowSet");
                JSONArray ja4;

                int count = 0;
                for(int i = 0;i<ja3.length();i++){
                    ja4 = new JSONArray(ja3.get(i).toString());
                    //teams+=ja4.get(4)+": score =  "+ja4.get(21).toString()+"\n";
                    if(count == 1) {
                        games.get(games.size() - 1).setTeam2(ja4.get(4).toString());
                        games.get(games.size() - 1).setTeam2_score(Integer.parseInt(ja4.get(21).toString()));
                        count = 0;
                    }else{
                        games.add(new Games(ja4.get(4).toString(), Integer.parseInt(ja4.get(21).toString())));
                        count = 1;
                    }
                    Log.d("AAAAAHHHHHHH",Integer.toString(games.size()));
                }




            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //main.setText(teams);

        }
    }
    run r = new run();

    r.execute();
    mAdapter = new GameAdapter(games);
    mGameRecycleViewer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter is already set before fetching the json data, so an empty list is probably being sent. You should be setting the adapter in the onPostExecute after the list has been fully filled with data:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //main.setText(teams);
        mAdapter = new GameAdapter(games);
        mGameRecycleViewer.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```